# how to Find the largest element in a list using recursion python?

Tags: python, recursion

```
i = 0

def find_max(seq):
if i == len(seq) - 1:
      return seq[0]
else:
      first = seq[i]
      i = i + 1
      max_of_rest = find_max(seq)
      return max(first, max_of_rest)
```

I do not know what is wrong with this function? It is a infinite loop.

Comment: Why would one do this recursively? you create lots of calls stackframes onto each other to use buildin `max` multiple time whereas `max(seq)` would do it in linear time and fewer memory needed?

Comment: @Patrick, one would do this recursively to learn programming. Why would someone starting to learn would need advice about stackframes and big O and memory usage with such a simple question?

Comment: @Mike there are "good" problems and "bad" problems for recursive programming - trees and linked lists come to mind. Doing recursion on a linear problem just for the sake of doing recursion is simply bad.

Comment: @Patrick then I find doing a constructive comment, or better even, posting an answer as the one you did, a better approach, as opposed to questioning a post for the sake of questioning.

Answer (score 1):

Please check out the following solution and follow comments:

```
def find_biggest(_list, max_element, first_run):
    """
    _list is a list of floats or integers or both,
    max element is used to store max value,
    first run checks if _list is not empty
    """
    if first_run and not _list:  # check if _list is not empty
        raise ValueError("_list should have float or integer values inside")

    first_run = False

    if not _list:  # exit from recursion, we checked all elements
        return max_element

    element = _list.pop()  # take one element

    if type(element) not in (int, float,):  # check element type
        raise TypeError("_list should contain only int or float values")

    if element >= max_element:  # check if it is more than max
        max_element = element

    return find_biggest(_list, max_element, first_run)  # next step of recursion


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # test
    print(find_biggest([-1, 4, 2, 3, 1, 0, 10, 3, 1, 7], 0, True))
    # print(find_biggest([], 0, True))  # empty case
    # print(find_biggest([-1, 4, 2, 3, "1", 0, 10, 3, 1, 7], 0, True))  # string in list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this:

```
def find_max(seq):
    if len(seq) == 1:
        return seq[0]
    else:
        if seq[0] > seq[1]:
            seq.pop(1)
        else:
            seq.pop(0)
        return find_max(seq)
```

Your code has a lot of indentation issues, that may skip execution of some lines.
Your code should look like this:

```
i = 0

def find_max(seq):
    global i
    if i == len(seq) - 1:
        return seq[0]
    else:
        first = seq[i]
        i = i + 1
        max_of_rest = find_max(seq)
        return max(first, max_of_rest)
```

You missed the global, and thus there is no definition of `i` inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

You are using uneeded `i` variable, in recursion you have base case (your first `if`), and recursion case, which in this case would be accessing first and second element of your list. As you already checked that the list `seq` has more than 1 element, you can confidently access positions 0 and 1 of the list.

In your specific case, you are not really using recursion because you never **reduce** your case, but instead you increment an `i` variable, whilst recursion is based on always calling the same function with a "simpler" or reduced problem.

With that in mind, several things can be improved in your solution.

```
i = 0 # Not adviced

def find_max(seq):
    # Here you want to check length, making it
    # depend on i = problems
    if i == len(seq) - 1: 
        return seq[0]
    else:
        first = seq[i] # Remove all references to i
        i = i + 1 # Remove
        # Here you want to call the function with the list
        # except the element you know is lower, making the problem
        # smaller until you get to the base case
        # Instead you are calling find_max with the same
        # sequence you had (infinite loop) and returning a
        # totally different result.
        max_of_rest = find_max(seq)
        return max(first, max_of_rest)
```

A complete solution based on your code would look like this

```
def find_max(seq):
    if len(seq) == 0:
        return None
    if len(seq) <= 1:
        return seq[0]
    else:
        current_max = max(seq[0], seq[1])
        reduced_seq = [current_max] + seq[2:]
        return find_max(reduced_seq)
```

Comment: Yours will crash (IndexError) for:  `find_max([])` and builds intermediate inner lists that are not needed for the recursion, but works otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains an `IndentationError` and does not reduce its data on recursive calls - hence data never getting shorter - hence never ending recursion:

> ```
> def find_max(seq):
>     if i == len(seq) - 1:   # fixed indentation here and below
>           return seq[0]
>     else:
>           first = seq[i]
>           i = i + 1
>           max_of_rest = find_max(seq)  # never reducing your data size, hence endless
>           return max(first, max_of_rest)
> ```

This would be a fixed recursive solution:

```
def find_max(seq):   
    if not seq:
        return None  # or raise ValueError if you want find_max([]) to crash
    if len(seq) == 1:
        return seq[0]
    else:
        return max(seq[0], find_max(seq[1:]))
```

---

The problem is inheritently bad for recursive solutions, it is far better to solve it linearly (no `max(..)` calls needed):

```
def find_max_lin(seq):
    if not seq:
        return None
    m = seq[0]
    for value in seq[1:]:
        m = m if value < m else value
    return m
```

or even better simply use the built in [max(sequence)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

```
def find_max_builtin(seq): 
    # no need to create your own function for that though
    return max(seq)
```

---

See [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator) for an explanation of what `m = m if value < m else value` does.

Answer (score -2):

```
i = 0

def find_max(seq):
    global i
    if i == len(seq) :
        return seq[0]
    else:
          first = seq[i]
          i = i + 1
          max_of_rest = find_max(seq)
          return max(first, max_of_rest)



print(find_max([-10,2,4,-5]))
```

thank me later